# Functions works locally but when using Live Server it is undefined, any idea what

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm trying to use Live Server for testing purposes. When running locally everything works fine; however, when ran using Live Server all of my functions error in console.

Additionally, all code is contained within my html document, no external JS or CSS files are in use.

[image: When ran locally (The error is expected & is being handled)]

[image: When ran on live server & calling keyVolume() function]

As you can see from the above images. Also here is the entirety of the function for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>LKT v2</title>
</head>

<body></body>
<hr id="system-readmore" />
<div class="container p-3">
    
    <input id="inputStd" class="input-element input_Style" type="text" placeholder="Enter License Key..." onkeyup="update();" />
    <input id="inputOld" class="input-elementOld input_Style hidden" type="text" placeholder="Enter License Key..." onkeyup="alternate();" />
    <input id="clearButton" class="clearBtn" type="submit" value="Clear" onclick="clearFnc();"/>
    
    <h5 class="pt-3 pl-2">License Key Details:</h5>
    <div>
        <p id="outVersion" class="pl-2">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="outModule" class="pl-2">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="outRegion" class="pl-2">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="outVolume" class="pl-2">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="outSupport" class="pl-2">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none !important;
    }
    
    input.input_Style,
    select {
        width: 30%;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        margin: 8px 5px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        input[type=text]:focus.inputStyle {
            width: 30%;
        }
    }
    
    input[type=submit].clearBtn {
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: #1085de;
        border: 2px solid #1085de;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 190px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
        transition: 0.5s;
        font-weight: 600;
        outline: none;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    input[type=submit]:hover.clearBtn {
        background-color: #61bbff;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 2px solid #61bbff;
        transition: border-radius 150ms ease;
        transition: 0.5s;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type=submit]:active.clearBtn {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script src="cleave.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var i = 0;
    var key = [];
    var fullKey;
    // output variables
    var ODMS = 'Version: Olympus Dictation Management System ';
    var R7 = 'Release 7 (ODMS R7) - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var R6 = 'Release 6 (ODMS R6) - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var DSS = 'Version: DSS Player ';
    var R4 = 'Pro Release 4 ';
    var R5 = 'Pro Release 5 ';
    var SR1 = 'Standard Release 1 - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var SR2 = 'Standard Release 2 - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var DSS6and7 = 'version 6 & 7 ';
    var DPFM = 'Version: DSS Player For Mac - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var R6SCP = 'ODMS R6 System Configuration Program (SCP) - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var R6LM = 'ODMS R6 License Manager - Download <a href="">here</a> ';
    var Express = ODMS + 'Express';
    var sonority = 'Version: Sonority ';
    var DSS2002 = 'Version: DSS Player 2002';
    var version = '';
    var module = '';
    var region = '';
    var usernum = '';
    var key2002 = false;
    var supported;
    yesSup = '<span style="color: green;">This product is currently supported</span>';
    noSup = '<span style="color: red;">This product is no longer supported</span>';
    var errorMSG = '<span style="color: red;">One or more characters are invalid, please check your key & try again.</span>'
    
    // Cleave for normal keys
    var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
        delimiter: '-',
        blocks: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        uppercase: true,
    });
    // Cleave for old keys
    var cleaveOld = new Cleave('.input-elementOld', {
        delimiter: '-',
        blocks: [4, 3, 3, 4],
        uppercase: true,
    });
    // Clear all function for 'Clear' button
    function clearFnc() {
        document.getElementById('inputStd').value = '';
        document.getElementById('inputOld').value = '';
        document.getElementById('outVersion').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('outModule').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('outRegion').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('outVolume').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('outSupport').innerHTML = '';
        region = '';
        usernum = '';
        key2002 = false;
        inputHandle();
    };
    // Error message for invalid inputs
    function keyError(){
        version = errorMSG;
        module = '';
        region = '';
        usernum = '';
        supported = '';
    }
    // Main function
    function update(){
        console.log('update');
        fullKey = document.getElementById('inputStd').value;
        key = document.getElementById('inputStd').value.split('-');
        switch(key[0].charAt(0)){
            // First character is 'R'
            case 'R':
            supported = '';
            version = '<span style="color: #ff9933">Please enter additional characters</span>';
            rKeyCheck();
            keyModule();
            R6serverComp();            
            break;
            // First character is 'S'
            case 'S':
            supported = '';
            version = DSS;
            keyModule();
            dssVersion();
            break;
            // First character is '8'
            case '8':               
            switch(key[0].charAt(1)){
                // DPFM
                case '2':
                supported = yesSup;
                version = DPFM;
                break;
                // DSS Player v6 / v7
                case '3':
                v6v7module();
                supported = noSup;
                version = DSS + DSS6and7;
                break;
                // Sonority
                case '5':
                supported = noSup;
                version = sonority;
                break;
                // Clear output if no value is entered
                case '':
                supported = '';
                version = '';
                break;
            }
            break;
            // Blank input removes output & resets
            case '':
            version = '';
            module = '';
            region = '';
            usernum = '';
            supported = '';
            key2002 = false;
            inputHandle();
            break;
            // If an unrecognised character is entered will error.
            default:
            keyError();
            break;
        }
        document.getElementById('outVersion').innerHTML = version;
        document.getElementById('outModule').innerHTML = module;
        document.getElementById('outRegion').innerHTML = region;
        document.getElementById('outVolume').innerHTML = usernum;
        document.getElementById('outSupport').innerHTML = supported;
    }
    // Function for 2002 keys
    function alternate(){
        fullKey = document.getElementById('inputOld').value;
        key = document.getElementById('inputOld').value.split('-');
        console.log('alt');
        switch(key[0].charAt(0)){
            // First character is 'R'
            case 'R':
            version = '<span style="color: #ff9933">Please enter additional characters</span>';
            module = '';
            supported = '';
            switch(key[0].charAt(1)){
                // Second character is 'D'
                case 'D':
                
                module = 'Module: Dictation Module'
                supported = '';
                switch(key[0].charAt(2)){
                    case '3':
                    version = DSS2002;
                    supported = noSup;
                    break;
                    default:
                    key2002 = false;
                    inputHandle();
                    break;
                }
                break;
                // Second character is 'F'
                case 'F':
                version = DSS2002;
                supported = '';                
                switch(key[0].charAt(2)){
                    case 'P':
                    module = 'Module: Transcription Module';
                    supported = noSup;                    
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
                default:
                key2002 = false;
                inputHandle();
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        document.getElementById('outVersion').innerHTML = version;
        document.getElementById('outModule').innerHTML = module;
        document.getElementById('outSupport').innerHTML = supported;
    }
    // Check module of key (Standard keys)
    function keyModule(){
        switch(key[0].charAt(1)){
            // DM
            case 'D':
            module = 'Module: Dictation Module';
            detect2002();
            break;
            //TM
            case 'T':
            module = 'Module: Transcription Module';
            break;            
            case '':
            module = '';
            supported = '';
            break;
            default:
            module = errorMSG;
            break;
        }
        switch(key[0].charAt(1)){
            case 'F':
            key2002 = true;
            version = DSS2002;
            inputHandle();            
            break;
        }
    }
    // Check region of key
    function keyRegion(){
        switch(key[0].charAt(3)){
            case '4':
            // USA
            region = 'Region: United States of America';
            break;
            case '6':
            // Europe
            region = 'Region: Europe';
            break;
            case '8':
            // Oceania
            region = 'Region: Oceania';                
            break;
            case '':
            region = '';
            break;
            default:
            region = errorMSG;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Check version for DSS software
    function dssVersion(){
        if(key[0].length >=3){
            switch(key[0].charAt(2)){
                case '1':
                // SR1
                version = DSS + SR1;
                supported = noSup;
                break;
                case '2':
                // SR2
                version = DSS + SR2;
                keyRegion();
                keyVolume();
                supported = yesSup;
                break;
                case '':
                supported = '';
                version = '';
                break;
                default:
                version = errorMSG;
                break;      
            }   
        }
    } 
    // Checks for keys beginning with 'R'
    function rKeyCheck(){
        if (key[0].length >= 3){
            switch(key[0].charAt(2)){
                // ODMS R7
                case '7':
                version = ODMS + R7;
                keyRegion();
                keyVolume();
                supported = yesSup;
                break;
                // ODMS R6
                case '6':
                version = ODMS + R6;
                keyRegion();
                keyVolume();
                supported = noSup;
                break;
                // R5
                case '5':
                version = DSS + R5;
                keyVolume();
                supported = noSup;
                break;
                // R4
                case 'M':
                version = DSS + R4;
                supported = noSup;
                break;
                default:
                keyError();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // R6 server components
    function R6serverComp(){
        switch(key[0].charAt(1)){
            case 'S':
            // R6 SCP
            version =  R6SCP;
            supported = noSup;
            break;
            case 'L':
            // R6 License Manager
            version = R6LM;
            supported = noSup;
            break;
            case 'R':
            // ODMS Express
            version = Express;
            keyVolume();
            supported = noSup;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Checks & outputs volume license amounts
    function keyVolume(){
        try{
            switch(key[1]){
                // Leaves blank until significant value is entered
                case null: case '': case '0': case '00': case '000': case '0000':
                usernum = '';  
                break;
                // Single-user license key
                case '0001':
                usernum = 'You have 1 concurrent key on your license!';
                break;
                // Calculates the Volume of the key
                default:
                hexnum = key[1].toString(16);
                keyAmount = parseInt((hexnum), 16);
                usernum = 'Your key has ' + keyAmount + ' concurrent licenses!';
                break;
            }
            // Catch error - error resolves once key[1] has a valid input, hence the catch
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
    // Check module of v6/v7 keys
    function v6v7module(){
        if (key[1].length >= 4){
            switch(key[1]){
                case '0101':
                module = 'Module: Dictation Module';
                break;
                case '0121':
                module = 'Module: Transcription Module';
                break;
                default:
                module = errorMSG;
                break;
            }            
        } else {
            module = '';
        }
        document.getElementById('outModule').innerHTML = module;
    }
    // 2002 key detection
    function detect2002(){
        switch(key[0].charAt(2)){
            case '3': 
            key2002 = true;
            inputHandle();
            alternate();
            break;
            default:
            key2002 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Handles input field change
    function inputHandle(){
        switch(key2002){
            // The key is for DSS Player 2002
            case true:
            document.getElementById('inputStd').classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById('inputOld').classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById('inputOld').focus();
            document.getElementById('inputOld').value = document.getElementById('inputStd').value;
            document.getElementById('inputStd').value = '';
            break;
            // The key is not for DSS Player 2002
            case false:
            document.getElementById('inputStd').classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById('inputOld').classList.add('hidden');
            document.getElementById('inputStd').focus();
            document.getElementById('inputStd').value = document.getElementById('inputOld').value;
            document.getElementById('inputOld').value = '';
            break;
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this to error or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

your code works neither locally nor using the live server and it shouldn't work because key is not defined.

You need to define key. There are no more errors when I define key at the beginning:

```
let key = ["0", "0001"];
```

Then, I added a log message for the case "0001" to test it and everything works fine now.

```
      // Single-user license key
      case "0001":
        console.log("Message successfully displayed!");
        usernum = "You have 1 concurrent key on your license!";
        break;
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Apologies, I did not include it in my initial question. I have defined key & all other variables within the document.

Comment: Can you please post or upload the whole code? I'm sure we'll find a solution quickly after that :)

Comment: I've added the rest, mind taking a look please?

Answer (score 1):

Live Server sends the HTML file. In order to use any JavaScript / CSS files we need to connect them to the HTML file via the link attribute in the head tags for CSS or in the end the body tag for JavaScript (or in the head tags with 'defer')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GoodBye</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>GoodBye World!!</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My CSS & JS is inside the local html file, when I check sources within the console all the code is shown which would suggest the Live Server can access the CSS & JS. Also, I have a JS library linked within the head tags; however, that is not showing as a source within the console. Do I still need to link them regardless? Should I use external files for CSS & JS?

Comment: Can you add your full html ?

Comment: Added the rest, can you see anything that might be causing the error?